# Pointer to array of unknown bound?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

The following function declaration is accepted by gcc, but not accepted by g++.

```
void do_something(char (*)[]);
```

The error given by g++ is:

```
error: parameter '<anonymous>' includes pointer to array of unknown bound 'char []'
```

I believe that in C, the parameter is converted to char** which is why gcc accepts it fine.

Can I make g++ accept this function somehow?

See example: http://ideone.com/yqvqdB :)

Thanks!

Comment: What is `do_something` actually looking to operate on?  Is it looking to operate on a `char**`, or a `char*`?

Comment: Depends on the compiler you want to use in the long run? Or do you want to use both?

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code you're compiling? That should indeed be equivalent to `char**`, and g++ accepts it: http://ideone.com/njdwyc. A pointer to an array would look like `char (*)[]`.

Comment: It's looking to operate on a char**. g++ in the long run :) thanks

Comment: Then why not declare it as a `char**` and be done with it? (Even though what you have is equivalent).

Comment: Thanks Mike, updated my question to show the correct syntax I'm using.

Comment: `void do_something (std::vector<std::string>& strings)` would be a nice way to get this working in C++.

Comment: http://ideone.com/WNwkYj Doesn't appear g++ accepts that.  I don't recall the standard allowing it either, though.

Comment: Your compiler is trying to allocate memory for the number of `char *`s in the array.

Comment: Pointer to array of unknown bounds is not allowed as a function parameter in C++11, but the restriction is lifted in C++14. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Arrays_of_unknown_bound.

Answer (score -1):

The GNU GCC compiler uses non-standard compilant to compile program. Add this flag `-std=c99` or `-std=iso9899:1999` to compile your program as a standard input and you will get an error.

In standard this will be always accepted as a pointer to an array, so you must provide the lenght of the array as it's required for pointers arithmitics.

Comment: That is false. In standard C language `char (*)[]` is a perfectly valid parameter declaration.