# Why is pointer to array of unknown bounds sometimes illegal?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, incomplete-type

When I declare a variable of this incomplete type it compiles fine under clang:

```
int (* a)[]
```

But when I declare a function parameter of the same type it fails. Any rationale?

```
void func(int (*)[])
```

Life [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1kTwST6qK5tZgisJ).

It's the same in 'gcc' also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570857/pointer-to-array-of-unknown-bound

Comment: I never find a good explanation there. They pointed out my first construction as illegal but it actually compiles. Also I'm comparing it's usage as a parameter and a variable declaration while the other one is describing the first case.

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate of a different question. Please comment if you feel the answers there do not answer your question. Note: as pointed out there, although it's currently invalid to use such types as function parameters, it's being made legal and so should compile without issues in a future version of C++.

Comment: a successfully compiled program doesn't neccessarily be a legal program